# Php associative array deleting a value on click

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, dynamic-arrays

I'm a newbie and I'm learning PHP so any help would be greatly appreciated.

I've been struggling a whole day with this
I have an array that represents user last actions and it just records
day - time - "type of action"  (and it's serialized and sent to mySQL DB.)

And I'm getting array like this:

---- EDITED ----

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [Date] => 2011-02-06 [Time] => 06:48 PM [Entry] => Email sent 0 test ) [1] => Array ( [Date] => 2011-02-06 [Time] => 06:48 PM [Entry] => Email sent 1 test ) [2] => Array ( [Date] => 2011-02-06 [Time] => 06:48 PM [Entry] => Email sent 2 test ) )
```

**And my question is, I want to add a small button/link in each row (when array is displayed) so that user can remove just that particular action**

```
foreach ( $actionhistory as $row ) {
  foreach ( $row as $key => $value ) {
   echo "foo delete record - $value";
  }
  echo '
';
}
```

Question:
user now sees this in his browser:

```
2011-02-0606:48 PM Email sent 0 test
2011-02-0606:48 PM Email sent 1 test
2011-02-0606:48 PME mail sent 2 test
```

I want to add a link before each date. So when users clicks on that link - external page will be loaded and that particular "record" needs to be removed from the list.

E.G. User wants to remove entry

```
[2] => Array ( [Date] => 2011-02-06 [Time] => 06:48 PM [Entry] => Email sent 2 test )
```

he will click on the link beside that entry.... and that's where I have a problem.
How do I remove that entry but keeping the rest ?

Comment: The array you are obtaining satisfies you? Shouldn't be `Array([0] => Array( [Date] => 2011-02-06, [Time] => 06:08 PM, [Entry] => Email sent 0 test), [1] => Array( [Date], [Time], [Entry] ))` instead?

Comment: I guess - I'm just learning about those stuff... So how to dynamically create that kind of array (i have 3 variables)?

Comment: You actually don't give any context information for your real question. How do you display the array? It seems like it is "just" adding a form, handle form submission and access DB. What of these things do you know and which not? Btw. to create a better array structure, do `$actionhistory[] = array($actionhistory_date, $actionhistory_time, $actionhistory_entry);`.

Comment: OK, sorry guys, I'm still a noob and I know I can't formulate the question well, but I hope you know now what i mean ? Thanks for your patience !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why all these variables? And your array is wrongly built.

```
$actionhistory[] = array(
  "Date" => date("Y-m-d"),
  "Time" => date("h:i A"),
  "Entry" => "Email sent ".$row." test" //This is actually user action
);
```

What you want is sending through javascript a particular row of actions' history to a PHP script, which will delete this row from the database, and maybe also dynamically remove the row from your table. You need to add another element to your array, which is the unique ID in the database, except if you've got a unique key with date/time/action - which seems pretty stupid! Then using a JS library such as jQuery, use a simple interaction on a delete button in your row like this:

```
<?php
while ( $data = $query->fetch() ){
  echo '<tr><td....</td>
    <td><input type="button" value="delete" onclick="
      $.post(\'myScript.php?id='.$data['id'].'\',function(d){
        if ( d == 1 ){
          $(this).parents("tr").eq(0).remove();
        }
      });" /></td</tr>';
}
?>
```

Then myScript.php should take care of $_POST['id'], delete the corresponding row, and echo 1 if it was successful, so the row is removed. [Edited, $_POST, not $_GET!]

Comment: Actually this is being serialized and then sent to a DB. Then (on other page - colorbox pop-up window)  I get the value, unserialize it, and then I display it to user. This all happens in a pop-up window, so that's why I need to pass it to the external file. External file will connect to DB unserialize it, than remove the value passed to it by user. than it will serialize it, upload it to DB and when it's done, users "popup" window will refresh - and that "action" will be gone... I know that there is Jquery doing this, but I just don't know Jquery :) ...barely know PHP :)

Comment: Ah sorry, I don't do popup refreshing anymore... You should get your hands on jQuery or Mootools, a simple JS library and discover the joy of not refreshing... I don't know why you want to serialize and unserialize so many times, but what you simply can do is having a link in your table, which calls the same page, but with your serialised row that you'd delete at the start of your script... Not sure I'm very clear, sorry - but neither are you!

Comment: Simple - I'm doing this because I don't know how to use Jquery at all... that's why so many serializing/deserializing... if I knew how to work with it - you bet I would have use it :)

Answer (score 0):

The way I understood it was that you need to pass the array to another file which is responsible for deleting it. All the rows should have an unique identificator in MySQL, so all you need to do it include the ID of the row you want deleted in the query string to the deletion file.

In case i misunderstood you and you want to send the array data itself to the other file, you can serialize the array, urlencode it and pass it through a query string.

Another alternative could be keeping all the arrays in $_SESSION and pass the index through the query string in the link.

I hope I helped (and understood the question)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot - I've sorted it by adding a unique ID, so on click only id is passed to the external file and then value from array is removed. Thanks NAAB for the tip !

When I paste a code here - system cuts the most important parts of it, but if somebody needs my solution, just ask and I'll send it...